# Runtime error on delete loop

Tags: vba, excel

Any ideas why I am getting run-time error type mismatch for the code below? There seems to be an issue with the if statement.

The run-time error is type mismatch

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell_search As Range
Dim del As Range
Dim FrRngCount As Range
Dim I As Integer
Dim DatatoData As Worksheet

Set DatatoData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PCA DATA2")

Set FrRngCount = DatatoData.Range("A:A")
I = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(FrRngCount)

Set rng = Intersect(DatatoData.Range("CV2:CV" & I), DatatoData.UsedRange)

For Each cell_search In rng
If (cell_search.Value) = "Not in Range" Then
    If del Is Nothing Then
        Set del = cell_search
    Else: Set del = Union(del, cell_search)
    End If
End If
Next cell_search
On Error Resume Next
del.EntireRow.Delete
```

Thanks for your help. Pete

Comment: What runtime error do you get?

Comment: The runtime error is type mismatch.

Comment: On which line are you getting this error?

Comment: @Ralph on this line: If (cell_search.Value) = "Not in Range" Then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is rng being set to Nothing?  Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim rng As Range
Dim cell_search As Range
Dim del As Range
Dim FrRngCount As Range
Dim I As Integer
Dim DatatoData As Worksheet

Set DatatoData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PCA DATA2")

Set FrRngCount = DatatoData.Range("A:A")
I = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(FrRngCount)    

Set rng = Intersect(DatatoData.Range("CV2:CV" & I), DatatoData.UsedRange)

If Not rng Is Nothing Then

For Each cell_search In rng
    cell_search.Activate
    If cell_search.Value = "Not in Range" Then
        If del Is Nothing Then
            Set del = cell_search
        Else: Set del = Union(del, cell_search)
        End If
    End If
Next cell_search

End If

On Error Resume Next
del.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

This is what I have and it seems to work.  I added the cell_search.Active for debugging.  You should give this a try and see what cell it activates when you get your error.

Comment: The compiler still stops in this row with the runtime error missmatch: If cell_search.Value = "Not in Range" Then

Comment: I cannot re-create your error.  In my test this corrected the issue.  What type of data are you expecting in rng?

Comment: The fields in the range display based on a formula either "In Range" or "Not in Range" .

Answer (score 1):

Based on your above comment (where the error occurs) it seems that the `.Value` of that cell cannot be determined. This is the case, when a formula is in that cell which produces an error (for example `#DIV/0!` or `#NAME?` or `#Ref!`).

So, I'd suggest that you test the cell's `.Value` first before you evaluate it:

```
For Each cell_search In Rng
    If IsError(cell_search.Value) Then
        'What should happen in this case?
    Else
        If (cell_search.Value) = "Not in Range" Then
            If del Is Nothing Then
                Set del = cell_search
            Else: Set del = Union(del, cell_search)
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next cell_search
```

Please let me know if this resolved the problem for you.

Comment: Thanks, the loop seems to be working now, however when I add del.EntireRow.Delete after the loop I get an error that the object variable is not set.

Comment: That means that rng is empty and therefore there is nothing to be deleted.

Comment: Still not working. Now it says that the method 'Union' of object _Global failed. Any suggestions on how to fix this?